# Ignore Assertion failure in a testcase (JUnit)

Tags: java, junit

Currently, I am writing the automation testing using java and selenium rc.

I would like to verify all the contents present on the user interface, the function is ie below:

```java
public String UITest() throws IOException {

    String result="Test Start<br />";

    try {
        openfile(1);
        for (String url : uiMaps.keySet()) {
            selenium.open(url);
            for (String item : uiMaps.get(url)) {                   
                assertEquals(url+" check: " + item, true,selenium.isTextPresent(item));
                result+=url+" check: " + item+" : OK<br />";
            }
        }
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        result+=e.getMessage();
    }
    result+="Test finished<br />";
    return result;
}
```

The function is supposed to return a String containing information about the testing. However, the function stopped once an assertion error happened.

Is there a way to ignore the failure and keep executing all the assertion verifications?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a [JUnit 4 error collector rule](http://junit-team.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/index.html?org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html):

> The ErrorCollector rule allows
>   execution of a test to continue after
>   the first problem is found (for
>   example, to collect *all* the
>   incorrect rows in a table, and report
>   them all at once)

For example you can write a test like this.

```
public static class UsesErrorCollectorTwice {
  @Rule
  public ErrorCollector collector= new ErrorCollector();

  @Test
  public void example() {
    String x = [..]
    collector.checkThat(x, not(containsString("a")));
    collector.checkThat(y, containsString("b"));             
  }
}
```

The error collector uses hamcrest Matchers. Depending on your preferences this is positive or not.

Comment: It seems it will execute all the testings even there is one failed. But I got another question. I check the API and it says that all the incorrect rows in a table, and report them all at once. My question is that any way I can grab the information of the table? Thanks.

Comment: Due the accessibility of the errors list of original errorcollector, I implemented my own errorcollector by inheriting the junit one. Now it works. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user638297 Yes it's not to hard to implement a MethodRule that does exactly what you want. Could you gather all the information you where looking for?

Comment: Is there anything similar for JUnit 5?

Answer (score 3):

From Selenium [documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html):

> All Selenium Assertions can be used in 3 modes: "assert", "verify", and "waitFor". For example, you can "assertText", "verifyText" and "waitForText". When an "assert" fails, the test is aborted. **When a "verify" fails, the test will continue execution, logging the failure**. This allows a single "assert" to ensure that the application is on the correct page, followed by a bunch of "verify" assertions to test form field values, labels, etc.

Comment: I thought the problem is the assertEquals function of JUnit rather than selenium since the function fo selenium I used is "isTextPresent" and it is only in charge of returning a boolean value. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, you always have choice between: *assert* TextPresent, *verify* TextPresent and *is* TextPresent. Each version has different behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've figured it out yourself by now: the try-catch should be inside the for loop, not outside of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't assert anything in the function. Return say null instead, and have whoever's calling it to keep going but then fail if the function returned null