# JUNIT Test Comparison only shows the first Mismatch even though it reports the correct number of failures

Tags: java, junit

[image: JAVA JUNIT Code]
The code basically just compares two files line by line and reports an error to the error collector every time a mismatch is found. However, although it reports the correct number of failures which is 4 in this case, the Result comparison window only shows the first one. I think this is because a new try/catch block is required for a separate entry in the Result Comparison window but in this case I am using a while loop and not sure how I can implement a separate try/catch block for each iteration. Anyone know how I can make the Result Comparison window of JUNIT show each mismatch. I have provided images of the code and the window. Thanks
[image: JUNIT Result Comparison]

Comment: You are talking about various elements in your code, but not showing any. Posting a link to a screenshot with the code will most likely not be looked at with the result of downvotes.

Comment: Why are you trying to do JUnit's job while testing your code?  Let JUnit test your code and deal with the exceptions.  If the lines aren't equal, let JUnit report on that instead of you having to "wag the dog" as it were.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an error collector rule as described in the accepted answer to this other question

[Ignore Assertion failure in a testcase (JUnit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147187/ignore-assertion-failure-in-a-testcase-junit)

Comment: I have already done that although I know that my screenshot doesn't show that part of the code.